# jquery for each on a map with index, key and value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, hashmap

If I have data which looks something like this:

```
x = {"key1":"val1", "key2":"val2", "key3", "val3"};
```

Is there any standard way to do a for each over them with a function that returns the key, value and index?

The way I would do it is define an array of keys and use the index to access it, but is there a simpler way?

something like:

```
$.each(x, function(i, k, v) {
    //... do something here
}
```

Comment: Just plain old  `for()` and manual counter?

Comment: Objects' keys are unordered in nature. Most browsers will iterate them in the order the properties were added, but they are not warranted to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Object.keys()`[<sup>link</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) along with `Array.prototype.forEach`[<sup>link</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

*Synopsis*

```
Object.keys( object ).forEach(function( element, index, array ) {
});
```

`Object.keys()` returns all own keys as *Array* and `.forEach()` loops over an array like shown above. Since we get an *Array* from `Object.keys()`, we can of course also apply `Array.prototype.sort()` on it, and access the keys in any order we like. For instance

```
Object.keys( object ).sort(function( a, b ) {
    return a.localeCompare( b );
}).forEach(function( element, index, array ) {
    console.log( object[ element ] );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create your own "index" if you will

```
var i =0;
$.each(...... {
    /* code */
    i++;
});
```